# Kafka Stream automatically read from new topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there any way to make my Kafka Stream application automatically read from the newly created topic?

**Even if the topic is created while the stream application is already running**?

Something like having a wildcard in topic name like this:

```java
KStream<String, String> rawText = builder.stream("topic-input-*");
```

### Why I need this?

Right now, I've multiple clients sending data(all with the same schema) to *their own topic* and my stream application reads from those topics. Then my application does some transformation and writes the result to a *single topic*.

Although all of the clients could write to the same topic, an unbehaving client could also write on behalf of someone else. So I've created individual topics for each client. The problem is, whenever a new client comes, I create the new topic and set the ACL for them with a script but that is not enough. I also have to stop my streaming application, edit the code, add the new topic, compile it, package it, put it on the server and run it again!

Comment: Now 5 clients but in future max 50 clients. How do I force clients to write to their own partition? Is there a ACL for partition?

Comment: I can't let the clients write to the same topic. Because I need to know which client wrote the message. Therefore I want them to send the clientI-ID in their message. But the problem is, any client can use someone else's client-id.

Comment: Although this doesn't address your full proble, might help a bit. If you move the topic to a config file, you wouldn't need to recompile/redeploy.

Comment: @Dhiraj I am actually planning to do it. But I will still need to restart my streams, so they get the new topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Streams supports patter subscription:

```java
builder.stream(Pattern.compile("topic-input-*"));
```

(I hope the syntax is right; not sure from the top of my head... But the point is, instead of passing in a `String` you can user an overload of the `stream()` method that takes a pattern.)

Comment: So will this make the consumer subscribe to the newly created topics even if the program is running?

Comment: Yes it will. Compare the corresponding consumer `subscribe()` method, that also takes a pattern: https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html